# How do i include the content of an url with query string in php

Tags: php, include

I want to include the header of our white label partner in our site with a snippet in php, but it doesnt work properly.

... does include the header - but ignores everything after the ?
this is the url to include (i changed the url before the "/":)

```
<?php
include (url-of-whitelablepartner/header-basic?includeVendorChunks=true);?>
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?
The include function should be ok, but i think i am making a mistake, trying to include the query string also.

Answer (score 1):

This is good way how to get hacked. `include` gets the referenced file and executes it as PHP script.

But to your question, you seem to miss quotes around the URL.

If you are trying to include merely some HTML from remote URL then `readfile("https://YOUR_URL/header-basic?includeVendorChunks=true");` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually trying to include code and that code expects a get parameter, just define the `$_GET` variable:

```
$_GET['includeVendorChunks'] = 'true';
include('http://url-of-whitelablepartner/header-basic');
```